# SSH Tunnel Port Forwarding using multiple ethernet device

Tags: ssh, proxy, tunnel

on Linux Ubuntu, I want each modem to do the ssh tunnel event using its own internet (not according to the selected network on the computer), is something like this possible?

[Example Diagram Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Lhg.jpg)

Comment: Your diagram is not clear. 1) Where do you want to do the port forwarding, on "Home computer" machine or on "X Server" machine? 2) **From** where **to** where should the ports be forwarded? 3) What is the 3proxy service doing and where does it fit in the whole image? Please tell more details what do you **exactly** want to do.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Server or desktop?